# How to get nullability of Java types using Kotlin reflection?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, nullable, checker-framework

When I use Kotlin reflection to get nullability of **Kotlin** properties like `val nullableString: String?` I get correct information in `isMarkedNullable` property of `KType`. It also works "inside" types like `val nullableList: List<String?>?` where not only whole list is nullable but also individual elements can be `null`.

I would like to use the same mechanism also for **Java** types. It partially works, for example when I have property like `public @javax.annotation.Nullable String text;`. But `@javax.annotation.Nullable` cannot be used like this `public List<@Nullable String> list;` because it doesn't have `TYPE_USE` target. So I would like to use `@org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable` but this annotation is ignored by Kotlin reflection.

Here is some test:

```java
public class KotlinReflectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Field field : TestClass.class.getFields()) {
            final KProperty<?> kProperty = ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinProperty(field);
            System.out.println(kProperty.getName() + " nullable: " + kProperty.getReturnType().isMarkedNullable());
        }
    }

    public static class TestClass {
        public String text;                                                              // false
        public @javax.annotation.Nullable String textJavax;                              // true
        public @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable String textJetbrains;                 // false
        public @org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable String textChecker;  // false
    }

}
```

which produces following output:

```
text nullable: false
textJavax nullable: true
textJetbrains nullable: false
textChecker nullable: false
```

Is it possible to tell Kotlin reflection which annotations to use? Do they plan to support Checker Framework? I would appreciate any comment. Thanks

Comment: The CheckerFramework annotations should already be supported. This [page in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) says that the full list can be found in the compiler sources, and here they are: [(link)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors.jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/load/java/JvmAnnotationNames.kt)

Comment: I saw this list of annotations supported by Kotlin compiler. That's why I was hoping that is should also work in reflections. Unfortunately it seems that Kotlin reflections work differently from Kotlin compiler.

Comment: `isMarkedNullable` supports only [runtime-retained nullability annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/is-marked-nullable.html).
So, reflection-aware annotations should have `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.